# Calculate hash rate in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography

I am attempting to calculate the hash rate of my IOS device. According to [Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation) and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-SHA256D), if I let H(M) be the SHA-256 hash of message M, then SHA-256D is simply H(H(M)). To calculate the rate ( Bitcoin specific here), I'd divide the number of processed hashes over the elapsed seconds, as mentioned [here](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Hashrate#How_can_I_calculate_how_many_hashes_I_generate_per_second.3F).

Here is my implementation in Swift, using [CryptoSwift](https://cryptoswift.io/):

I first generate 10000 random strings to hash:

```
func generateRandomStrings() -> [String] {
    var randomStrings = [String]();
    for _ in 0..<10000 {
        randomStrings.append(NSUUID().uuidString);
    }
    return randomStrings;
}
```

I then take the sha256d of each:

```
import CryptoSwift

@IBAction func performHash(_ sender: Any) {

    var generatedStrings = generateRandomStrings();
    let info = ProcessInfo.processInfo;
    let begin = info.systemUptime;
    for i in 0..<generatedStrings.count {
        // calcualte the SHA256d
        _ = (generatedStrings[i].sha256()).sha256();
    }
    let diff = (info.systemUptime - begin);
    let hashPerSec = Double(generatedStrings.count) / diff;

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hash Rate", message: "Your hash rate is \(hashPerSec) h/s", preferredStyle: .alert);
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)

}
```

If I output the results, I get 24000 hashes per second! While I have no doubt that my IOS device ( iPhone SE ) is a creation of miracle, I am pretty sure it does not outperform an [iPhone 6](https://www.coinstaker.com/iphone-mine-cryptocurrencies/) by over 200% .

So obviously, as much as I love to see such amazing results, I question where fallacies or bugs lie either in my understanding or even code.

What am I doing wrong in my attempt to calculate the hash rate?

Comment: Try XORing the results of the hash results into a single result array, and then print out the the contents of that array at the end. The compiler may outsmart you if you don't use the results of a cryptographic hash by simply skipping the calculation altogether. (Damn you, Airplane movie, I cannot write that without repeating the last sentence in my head as a chorus). I presume Swift is a bit more like Java in that sense, compared to Objective C.

Comment: You can't compare results of two different tests. The crypto currency test incorporates a formula that has to be solved. In the end a hash is generated, but the formula calculation is also included in the speed. Therefore just performing some hashes creates totally different results.

Comment: @Robert I'll have to challange you a bit on that comment, as this question : https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28227/how-is-hash-rate-of-mining-hardware-calculated : seems to state otherwise. It only mentions the header, which is a teeny tiny 80 bytes long.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I assigned it to a variable, and appended the results to an array, with no difference in result. Very good thought however, I actually completely overlooked the compiler level details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results, while different, are the true way to calculate the hash rate. It can be optimized ofc, as mentioned [by this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84928/hash-rate-algebraic-equation/84929#84929) , to perform even better. The only modification needed above is to instead of a UUID use a string of variable length ( 80 characters, however, as mentioned in the lined description, that might be modifiable based on engineering strategy ).

```
func generateRandomStrings(numStrings: Int, lenString: Int) -> [String] {
    var randomStrings = [String]();
    for _ in 0..<numStrings {
        randomStrings.append(randomStringWithLength(length: lenString));
    }
    return randomStrings;
}

func randomStringWithLength (length : Int) -> String {
    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    let len = UInt32(letters.length)
    var randomString = ""
    for _ in 0 ..< length {
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
        var nextChar = letters.character(at: Int(rand))
        randomString += NSString(characters: &nextChar, length: 1) as String
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

Then, to create an array of strings ( 500 in this case ) that you could test with, you can use something like this:

```
let generatedStrings = HashingUtils().generateRandomStrings(numStrings: 500, lenString: 80);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the hash rate is affected by the size of the strings that are being hashing. The original article you link to doesn't describe what's being hashed, perhaps that's implicitly obvious to cryptocoin developers.

You can test this by doing several tests each test with generated strings of the same length. But changing that length between tests.

Comment: so I updated the message string to be 5K characters long, and by doing so, I get 4K hashes per second. Which is still very much. Makes me wonder if there is a standard length for this message, and google is not helping atm.

Comment: I found out that the standard message being hashed is 80 characters, so the size standard does exist. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation However, making it that small, just makes the calculations jump.